# Finding mode in Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

Suppose that $X$ has the Binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$ . How can I show that if $(n+1)p$ is integer then
$X$ has two mode that is $(n+1)p$ or $(n+1)p-1?$

Comment: Hint: compute the ratio $b(n,p;k+1)/b(n,p;k)$ and check that this ratio is $\gt1$ for every $k\lt k^*$ and $\leqslant1$ for every $k\geqslant k^*$, for some integer $k^*$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $a_k=P(X=k)$, we have
$$a_k=\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}\qquad\text{and}\qquad a_{k+1}=\binom{n}{k+1}p^{k+1}q^{n-k-
1},$$
where as usual $q=1-p$ in binomial distribution.

We calculate the *ratio* $\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$. Note that
$\frac{\binom{n}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$
simplifies to
$\frac{n-k}{k+1},$
and therefore
$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\cdot\frac{p}{q}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\cdot\frac{p}{1-p}.$$

From this equation we can follow:

$$\begin{align}
k > (n+1)p-1 \implies a_{k+1} < a_k \\  
k = (n+1)p-1 \implies a_{k+1} = a_k \\
k < (n+1)p-1 \implies a_{k+1} > a_k
\end{align}$$

The calculation (almost) says that we have equality of two consecutive probabilities precisely if $a_{k+1}=a_k$, that is, if $k=np+p-1$.  Note that $k=np+p-1$ implies that $np+p-1$ is an integer.

So if $k=np+p-1$ is not an integer, there is a single mode; and if $k=np+p-1$ is an integer, there are two modes, at $np+p-1$ and at $np+p$.

**Not quite!** We have been a little casual in our algebra. We have not paid attention to whether we might be multiplying or dividing by $0$.  We also have casually accepted what the algebra seems to say, without doing a reality check.

Suppose that $p=0$. Then $np+p-1$ is an integer, namely $-1$. But whatever $n$ is, there is a single mode, namely $k=0$. In all other situations where $np+p-1$ is an integer, the $k$ we have identified is non-negative.

However, suppose that $p=1$. Again, $np+p-1$ is an integer, and again there is no double mode. The largest $a_k$ occurs at one place only, namely $k=n$, since $np+p$ is in this case beyond our range.

That completes the analysis when $np+p-1$ is an integer. When it is not, the analysis is simple. There is a single mode, at $\lfloor np+p\rfloor$.

To summarize in a single formula:
$$\mathrm{mode(s)} = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } p = 0; \\
n, & \text{if } p = 1; \\
np + p - 1 \text{ and } np + p, & \text{if } np + p - 1 \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } 0 < p < 1; \\
\lfloor np + p \rfloor, & np + p - 1 \notin \mathbb{Z}. 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am solving a similar exercise and I have some doubts: why taking the ratio $\frac{p_X(k+1)}{p_X(k)}$ gives you the mode (most probable value), which is defined as $\sup_{x \in R_X} p_X(x)$?

Comment: The sup is in this case a max, since the random variable takes on integer values. Apart from a couple of "degenerate" cases pointed out in the answer, the probabilities rise and then fall. The ratio of consecutive terms is therefore $\gt 1$ for a while, then $\lt 1$, except that in somewhat unusual cases we can have ratio $1$, so two consecutive values each qualify as a mode. Looking at the ratios tells us when the probability has reached a maximum.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. That was an overview. The detail is in the answer above.