# Questions about solution to finding solution to mode of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution

So i read over the solution presented by Andre Nicolas:

[Finding mode in Binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117926/finding-mode-in-binomial-distribution)

But i have a few questions about the whole thing:

1) why did he set the ratio as $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$? Is each possible probability value a part of a sequence?

2) what is special about setting our ratios $\geq$ and $\leq$ 1?

3) Is there something special about being an integer? Does it have to do with being a discrete distribution?

4) what is the meaning of $k = np+p-1$ vs the other scenarios where it is not equal to k?

Sorry about the flurry of questions, but what appears as me understanding what is fully going on is not the case and there are some subtle points i am missing

Comment: We have $a_{k+1}\gt a_k$ if and only if $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\gt 1$, with similar results for $\ge$, $=$, $\lt$, and $\le$. The *ratio* of consecutive binomial coefficients is reasonably easy to compute.

Comment: So are "binomial coefficients" the probabilities that we obtain if we calculated some values in the  mass function?

Comment: Not quite, the binomial distribution probabilities  involve, in addition  to the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{j}$, powers of $p$ and $1-p$, which is often called $q$. What I found was the ratio of consecutive binomial probabilities, which involved ratios of binomial coefficients and a little more.

Comment: I don't mean to be a bother, but what is the difference between the two? And also question 3 and 4 that i had.

Comment: The probability $a_k$ that the binomial random variable takes on value $k$ is $\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$. The binomial coefficient is plain $\binom{n}{k}$. I will try to answer your other question later.

Comment: About $k=np+p-1$, and in particular $np+p-1$ being an integer, this has nothing to do with discreteness. The binomial distribution is a discrete distribution for all values of $n$ and $p$. The condition $k=np+p-1$ comes out of the analysis, it is the condition for bimodality.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope others will provide extended answers.

Comment: Then it is the analysis of what's happening that is confusing me